# Nuxt3 access to useNuxtApp() and i18n from helpers files

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, pinia, nuxt3, nuxt-i18n

I'm relatively new to Nuxt.js 3, having previously worked with Vue and Vuetify2. I've recently initiated a project using Vuetify3 and Nuxt3, encountering a few challenges.

In my previous projects, I relied on helper files for streamlined processes. In the current project, I'm using @nuxtjs/i18n for internationalization and need to access it from the store to translate data fetched from an API.

Additionally, I'd like to leverage `useNuxtApp()` in helper files to access plugins and utilize them outside of Vue components.

Any guidance on efficiently incorporating these aspects into my Nuxt3 project would be highly appreciated.

I  found workaround but I do not know if it is good or not

```
// plugins/helper.ts
let appInstance; // Declare a variable to store the app instance

export default defineNuxtPlugin((app) => {
  appInstance = app; // Assign the app instance to the variable  
});

// Export the app instance
export const getAppInstance = () => {
  return appInstance;
};
```

Then I can call it from anywhere like this

```
import { getAppInstance } from "@/plugins/helprs";

const app = getAppInstance();
alert(app.$i18n.t("hello"));
```